# Point cloud to CAD model

Tags: graphics, models, point-cloud

Point clouds can be obtained from a physical camera using phase shift algorithm. These may be 3-4 separate point clouds. My job is to combine those point clouds (register, filter) using signal processing algorithms to create a CAD model.

How can I do this? Are there existing tools or libraries I can use?

There are C/C++ point cloud libraries, but I'm using C#. Is there a way to use those libraries in C#?

Comment: For your point cloud registration and other operations have a look into PCL (www.pointclouds.org). As for a CAD model, you might want to clarify what it exactly is you want to achieve. Update: missed the point about C#. I don't think PCL has a wrapper/binding for C# at the moment, but perhaps it's worth the effort of doing something like it yourself.